# How to get nested property name (as flatten value) from linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I came up with the following. But the code does not look nice:

```
public static class GenericHelper<TEntity> {

    //This method uses my extension method, but it returns plain property name
    public static string GetPropertyName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression) {

        return propertyExpression.GetPropertyName();
    }

    //This method is used to return nested property name as dot-separated value
    public static string GetPropertyFlattenName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertyExpression) {

        //TODO: check TEntity, if needed. Now it's ignored

        var member = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (member == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.", propertyExpression));
        }

        var propertyInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

        if (propertyInfo == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.", propertyExpression));
        }

        //Suppposing it's the only one for this method
        var parameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0].Name;

        return propertyExpression.Body.ToString().Replace(string.Format("{0}.", parameter), "");
    }
}
```

I found no way to extract flatten property name in a more intelligent and elegant way.

Just want to specify: first method is used like this:

```
GenericHelper<MyEntity>.GetPropertyName(entity => entity.Property)
```

But if i have a nested property, like entity.Property.NestedProperty - i need to use my second method:

```
GenericHelper<MyEntity>.GetPropertyFlattenName(entity => entity.Property.NestedProperty)
```

to return "Property.NestedProperty" instead of "NestedProperty".

Comment: Well, you could return `propertyInfo.Name`. And maybe you shouldn't use a generic class type argument but add a generic argument to the method so you can use it as an extension method.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I've edited my question to explain, why propertyInfo.Name does not suit me (i need a dot-separated format).